# ATTACH INDEXEDDB DATABASE always fails on first try and succeeds on second

Tags: alasql

I am not sure what if anything I am doing wrong or if this is a bug.

My IndexedDB exists and has data in it. I am currently using alasql to query the data AFTER i retrieve it from IndexedDB, however I would much rather do this in a singe step as this make joins and other queries across multiple tables much simpler.

Here is my code:

```
const queryDB = async (dbName, query) => {
  const result = await alasql.promise([
    `CREATE INDEXEDDB DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${dbName};`,
    `ATTACH INDEXEDDB DATABASE ${dbName};`,
    `USE ${dbName};`,
  ]);
  console.log(result);
  return await alasql.promise(query);
};
```

(also tried without semicolon...)

the first call to this function fails with 'Error: Database ... does not exist' where ... is the dbName

while the second one succeeds and returns the value from the query.

I have been trying just about everything I can everything I can think of and the only working solution is using callbacks (as in the example on the wiki) which is NOT what I want to do.

Comment: What happens if there's a hardcoded delay before returning?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough this work:

```
const queryDB = async (dbName, query) => {
  await alasql.promise(`ATTACH INDEXEDDB DATABASE ${dbName};USE DATABASE ${dbName};`);
  return await alasql.promise(query);
};
```